# Determining dashboard usage in Grafana

Tags: grafana

Does anyone have a way to determine how often dashboards are accessed and which are not used at all? It'd be nice to have a way to prune never used/broken dashboards when the number of dashboards is > 1k. Setting the log levels to 'Trace' does not provide any information that would be usable in this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Grafana configuration](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/) docs you need to enable
**router_logging** option in `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`:

> Set to true for Grafana to log all HTTP requests (not just errors). These are logged as Info level events to grafana log.

Then you can find dashboard requests in `/var/lib/grafana/grafana.log` like this:

> t=2017-12-07T11:53:55+0300 lvl=info msg="Request Completed" logger=context userId=0 orgId=3 uname= method=GET path=/api/dashboards/db/`<name-of-your-dashboard-here>` status=200 remote_addr=.....

So you be able to filter and parse logs to extract dashboard usage stats.